# MYSQL query related data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I would like to query related data from an additional table, where I am able to get the lowest associated value...

**Example of two tables**

```
products
id          name          description
0           product_1     short description of 1
1           product_2     short description of 2

prices
id          product_id          option        price       personal
0           1                   3             10.00       1
1           0                   2             15.00       1
2           1                   3             5.00        0
3           1                   3             8.00        0
4           0                   2             7.00        1
```

**Output needed**

```
id          name          description       price     option
0           product_1     short ...         7.00      2
1           product_2     short ...         10.00     3
```

The query I am basically attempting to make is one which gets all associated fields, gets the associated data from prices where personal = 1 and has the lowest price.

**Current query** (getting lowest price but not associated option)

```
SELECT products.*, prices.option, 
   (SELECT ROUND( MIN( price ), 2) FROM prices WHERE product_id = products.id AND personal = 1) AS price 
FROM products 
ORDER BY price_low ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a join instead of a subquery and grouping by products? It should look something like this:

```
SELECT products.*, ROUND(MIN(prices.price), 2), prices.option
FROM products
INNER JOIN prices ON products.id = prices.product_id
WHERE prices.personal = 1
GROUP BY products.id
```

I tried it out on SqlFiddle, [here are the results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/152f3/3/0).

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't seem to bring the correct option value back. If I have the option value to another number on the line with 7.00 as the lowest price its still returns the value 2 from another line. Thank you for your input

Comment: Can you please elaborate? The table in your example has option 2 for value 7.00 and option 3 for value 15.00 and your example of the output needed show these as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an inner join   and a subselect with and group by for get the min price

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.description, pr.option, pr.price 
FROM products as p
inner join ( 
  select product_id, min(price) as price 
  from price 
  where personal = 1
  group by product_id

  ) t  on t.product_id= p.id
inner join price as pr on pr.product_id = p.id and pr.price = t.price
where pr.personal =1
group by   p.id, p.name, p.description, pr.option
ORDER BY pr.price ASC
```

Comment: Thank you but this query does not return the option value from the same line as the lowest price.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback on this question. After a lot of trail and error I finally got the needed result, here it is:

```
SELECT products.*, b.*, products.id as id FROM `products` 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM 
        ( SELECT * FROM prices ORDER BY product_id ASC, price ASC ) 
    as c GROUP BY product_id) 
AS b ON b.product_id = products.id 
WHERE `price` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `product_id` ASC
```